# Symbol at the end of an environment

Tags: math-mode, environments

I'm putting a diamond symbol at the of a remark by use of

> \usepackage{amsthm}
>
> ...
>
> \newenvironment{rem}{\begin{remark}}{\hfill$\diamond$\end{remark}}

However when the rem environment is finished with a math display mode, the diamond will be placed at the end of a new line. I would prefer that it is placed on the line of the equation.

How is this possible?

Comment: Off topic: usually we use `remark` as a theorem like environment defined with `\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As you see, the question has already been asked before; don't worry, it happens to new users and I knew what to look for. I obviously recommend my solution. `;-)` (Use `\qedhere` in the case you mention.) If you have remarks, please add them as comments here.

Comment: @egreg, that solution works when it ends with display math?

Comment: @Sigur If you use `\qedhere` in the display. The alternative is `ntheorem`, which I don't like at all.

Comment: @egreg: off-topic comment: Why do you not like `ntheorem`? Any particular issues in setup/typography? (Asking as a non-user of it)